# Python Sockets Io Client - Windows service

Tags: python, flask

I created sockets Io server with flask framework and now I wanted to create a client as a Windows service.
Unfortunately, the client connects to the server but does not react to events. Only work if I debug a service. A video showing the problem https://streamable.com/ggkzv6

```py
class ClientService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    sio = None
    _svc_name_ = "TarkaClientService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Tarka Client Service"
    _svc_description_ = "My service description"
 
    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        self.sio = Client()
        self.sio.register_namespace(ClientNamespace('/clients'))
 
    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
     
 
    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.sio.connect('http://localhost:5000/', namespaces='/clients')
 
        rc = None 
        # if the stop event hasn't been fired keep looping  
        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:  
            # block for 5 seconds and listen for a stop event  
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 5000)
 
        self.sio.disconnect()
         
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(ClientService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(ClientService)
```

Comment: Are there are any errors? Can you tell us more about the issue? Please edit the post with additional information that can help us understand the underlying issue.

Comment: A video showing the problem https://streamable.com/ggkzv6 and i don't see any errors.